# Portrait setup for desktop?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, viewport

I want to create a portrait based game for Android, but what I usually do to test most things is running it on my desktop. Now I want to create a portrait type of game, but my desktop screen is not high enough to even display 720*1280 resolution. I want to use the full 1080*1920 resolution on my phone and I do not mind if the desktop version is scaled down a bit.

Furthermore, I do not use stages, screens and viewports. It's a simple game, so I do not bother with the stage hierarchy unless it is advised in this case.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. Are you saying you are testing your app in an emulator, but the screen of your computer is too small?

Comment: @XaverKapeller i think he means the following: The phone has a resolution of 1080*1920px. The Desktop instead has 1920*1080, so he can't test the "real" resolution on desktop, cause the desktop monitor is landscape, while the phone is portrait-mode.

Comment: I would just test it on a real device and spare myself all that trouble... But if I remember correctly scaling the AVD down should be no problem.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: If @Springrbua is correct in assumption, you could try rotating the monitor 90deg and rotate the display of the OS to rotate 90deg, which gives you portrait. (Right click desktop->Resolution->Orientation->Portatir)

Comment: @CodeMonkey yea right, that would be the best solution, if i did not missunderstand his problem^^

Answer (score 2):

> Furthermore, I do not use stages, screens and viewports.

Sadly, you will have to take into account viewport and camera this time. If you are using LibGDX's orthographic camera, setting it up for fixed view port is really easy:

```
if(Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Desktop) {
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 1080, 1920);
} else {
    camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

or just create it with proper viewport right away

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(1080, 1920);
```

But this way Y-axis will be pointing up from the bottom of the screen. (By setting setToOrtho(true, ...), Y-axis is pointing down from the top of the screen.)

If you are using perspective camera, just create it with fixed viewport in constructor. Now you can init the app with any width/height and your whole view will be stretched (scaled down) to it. Until you keep aspect ratio, everything should be ok.

To read more about viewports, cameras and projection, be sure to check out interesting wiki article [on libgdx github.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Projection,-viewport,-&-camera)

Comment: I am actually expirimenting with flexible width/height. With success, i first calculate the actual screen width of the device then deviding that by the width I want to draw too (1080 in this case). If I devide the device height by that number I have my height i need to draw too. Now I just set my ortho cam to 1080 and the calculated height and I can change the desktop resolution to any size and everything scales up to the bounds. Just need to take care of stretching.

Comment: So does this answer your question? Or I might not understood it.

Comment: Yes it is an answer but a lot more complicated then my method with flexible resolutions.